# Adding meta boxes to custom post type

Tags: metabox

The `add_meta_box()` function needs a callback function as an argument to display the meta box on the edit page of a custom type post. My problem is I can not display anything, say in the `input type=text` (for example the values of an already posted post), because I don't have the ID of the post...

`get_post_meta` needs the ID of the post to display the values!

How can I get the ID of the post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let’s say your post type is named `product`. You register your metabox with …

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_product', 'register_product_metabox' );

function register_product_metabox()
{
    // register the metabox
}
```

You get the post id in your callback per post object now:

```
function metabox_callback( $post )
{
    $field = get_post_meta( $post->ID );
}
```

This happens because WordPress calls the callback with:

```
call_user_func($box['callback'], $object, $box);
```

See `wp-admin/includes/template.php`.

Comment: But where does the $post argument come from? When I give add_meta_box the callback function, I give it like a string 'myCallbackFucking' and I don't think I can pass an argument like that.

Comment: WordPress sends it when it calls the callback.

Comment: Oh ok. And how do we know what are the arguments wordpress passes in the callbacks/functions? Ex: add_action( 'save_post', 'add_movie_review_fields', 10, 2); passes 2 arguments, but what are the 2 arguments?

Comment: You have to look at the source code in WordPress. This is the only reliable source anyway.